# Remove text in 'a' but not in 'href'

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, cookies, replace

please take a look at my website: [moskah.nl](http://moskah.nl/links.html)

As you can see there is a pre-filled input. Click 'save' and you will see the url is being saved with a favicon next to it. Do this a couple of times to create a list.

If you refresh the page you will see the part that says 'http://' is being removed because of a function:

```
function replace() {
    $("a").text(function(i, h){
     return h.replace('http://', "");
  });  

}
```

Now the problem is that if you then click on a list item (NOT the href) you will see the item is being removed. Now if you refresh agian you will see all the favicons are gone. I think this is because somehow the function 'replace' is also removing the 'href' part which is strange because I explicitly stated it should remove 'text'. So how do I remove an item list without its favicon? (Basically keeping its url(href) intact)

ps. I cant give you a demo on jsfiddle because it doesnt work there.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the issue on jsFiddle, I imagine it's something other than your `replace` function. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @Kyle When I put it in JsFiddle and click on the 'save' it return something with: "use post" I dont know what that is but it doesnt work

Comment: your code needs some serious refactoring, for some reason the callback seems to be applying to all the links

Comment: @atif089 It shouldn't matter. The link consist out of two parts. One part that is the actual url like this: `href="someUrl"` The other part is this: `someUrl</a>` The function is addressing plain text which is the last part. It shouldn't do anything with the first part (but it does...)

Comment: The easiest way to get rid of your problem is to rewrite the whole thing. It suppose to be no longer than 30 lines.

Comment: The problem is linked to the deletion of nodes after you add it. Add four lines, delete one, refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('a[href^="http://"]', this).each(function () {
    // ...
}
```

You add the favicon inside this function; this means that if your `a` tag's href attribute doesn't start with `http://` it won't have a favicon.
When you populate the list with the jquery cookie:

```
if (cookie){
    var values = $.parseJSON(cookie);
    var li;
    for (var v in values) {
        li = $('<li><a href="' + values[v]+ '">' + values[v] + '</a></li>');
        $('.jq-text').append(li).show();

    }
// ...
}
```

the attribute href is set the same as the `a` tag's text:

```
li = $('<li><a href="' + values[v]+ '">' + values[v] + '</a></li>');
```

You have to save the href attribute inside the cookie too or to manually add `http://` when you load from the jquery cookie.

PS: sorry for my bad english; I wish that it's understandable what I've written.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and effort, really appreciate it:) Im going to try this, I will let you know if(when) I succeed.